# Project Euler: Largest palindrome (Python). What did I do wrong?

Tags: python, math, palindrome

I may have done many things wrong as I am only a beginner. But would someone please help me? The goal is to print the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers. Thanks.

```
palindromes = []
for i in range(100, 1000):
    for x in range(100, 1000):
        a = x*i
        str(a)
        b = a[::-1]
        if a == b :
            palindromes.append(a)

print (palindromes[len(palindromes) - 1])
```

Comment: missing colon after `range(100, 1000)` and x is not defined. Which project euler exactly (number) is this for?

Comment: @Keatinge I did those things in the actual code. I just forgot them here. This is the fourth problem in the archive.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  This code still doesn't run; you've failed to provide the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic points:

- When you convert the number to a string, you have to store the result.
- Sort the list when you're done.
- Use right-end indexing to get the last element
- When you find a palindrome, keep the *integer* form, so the sort works properly.  Otherwise, you get '99999' as the largest palindrome.

Code:

```
palindromes = []
for i in range(100, 1000):
    for x in range(100, 1000):
        a = str(x*i)
        b = a[::-1]
        if a == b :
            palindromes.append(int(a))

print (sorted(palindromes)[-1])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked!

Comment: Great!  Remember to up-vote useful answers and accept your favourite.  This allows SO to properly archive the question.

Answer (score 2):

You use `x` in your code before defining it, so you will get an error with that code. You have other errors as well: you should be able to find them easily using the tracebacks. One logic error is that you find the string of `a` but do not store it anywhere, so it is lost. You also start with `a` as an integer then try to make it a string: keep your types separate, unless you have an excellent reason to change the type. You should use better variable names: `a,b,i,x` are lousy names. Write down what they mean! Typing a few more characters is cheap and will prevent errors.

Each palindrome must be the product of *two* three-digit numbers, so you will need *two* nested loops over `range(100, 1000)`. Use `x` as your other loop variable and you will not need to change your code much.

Comment: Oh yes, I did have another for loop for x but I forgot to put that. I will add that. Thank you. I changed a to a string so that I could reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

Before printing, add line:

```
palindrome.sort()
```